# systemd-journald: Missed 685 kernel messages

Tags: systemd-journald

At boot and some other times I see missed kernel logs on my system.
After that I set Rate limits at jornald.conf but no luck. I still have the issue. 
Do you have any advice?

Kernel: 4.14.19-1-lts ARCH-Linux

My jornald conf:

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
Compress=yes
Seal=yes
SplitMode=uid
SyncIntervalSec=20
RateLimitIntervalSec=0
RateLimitBurst=0
RuntimeMaxUse=1G
MaxRetentionSec=1month
MaxFileSec=1h
ForwardToSyslog=no
ForwardToKMsg=no
ForwardToConsole=no
ForwardToWall=no
SystemMaxUse=2G
```

Log:

```
journalctl -b -n 1000000
-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-02-20 12:52:17 +03, end at Wed 2018-02-21 15:50:06 +03. --
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 systemd-journald[2411]: Missed 682 kernel messages
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:02.2: [8086:6f06] type 01 class 0x060400
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:02.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:03.0: [8086:6f08] type 01 class 0x060400
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:03.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.0: [8086:6f20] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf1c000-0xfbf1ffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.1: [8086:6f21] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf18000-0xfbf1bfff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.2: [8086:6f22] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.2: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf14000-0xfbf17fff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.3: [8086:6f23] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf10000-0xfbf13fff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.4: [8086:6f24] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.4: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf0c000-0xfbf0ffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.5: [8086:6f25] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.5: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf08000-0xfbf0bfff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.6: [8086:6f26] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.6: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf04000-0xfbf07fff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.7: [8086:6f27] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:04.7: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf00000-0xfbf03fff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:05.0: [8086:6f28] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:05.1: [8086:6f29] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:05.2: [8086:6f2a] type 00 class 0x088000
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:05.4: [8086:6f2c] type 00 class 0x080020
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:05.4: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfbf20000-0xfbf20fff]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: [1000:0097] type 00 class 0x010700
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xf000-0xf0ff]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xfbe00000-0xfbe0ffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xfbd00000-0xfbdfffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfbc00000-0xfbcfffff pref]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: supports D1 D2
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 0x174: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: VF(n) BAR0 space: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 0x17c: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:81:00.0: VF(n) BAR2 space: [mem 0x00000000-0x00ffffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 81]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:01.0:   bridge window [io  0xf000-0xffff]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:80:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfbc00000-0xfbefffff]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: [1000:0097] type 00 class 0x010700
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xe000-0xe0ff]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xfbb00000-0xfbb0ffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xfba00000-0xfbafffff 64bit]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfb900000-0xfb9fffff pref]
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: supports D1 D2
Feb 20 21:28:26 DEV1 kernel: pci 0000:82:00.0: reg 0x174: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff 64bit]
```